# how to wait load() complete and get variable in selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

my problem to get text in td after .load(url) to variable

load code

```
$("#tr1").load("include/test.php?page=1");
```

and code for get variable in .load(include/test.php?page=1)
i can not getid 
run before complete load

```
$(window).bind('load', function () {
          var getid = $("td:first").text();
          function updatenewrow(getid) {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: 'test1.php',
                  data: {id: getid},//only input
                  success: function (response) {
                      if (response > getid) {

                          $("#tr1").load("include/test.php?page=1");
                      }
                  }
              });
          }
          //setInterval(updatenewrow(getid), 4000);
      });
```

Comment: for loading img   function Hide_Load() {
               $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
            };

Comment: Change `Hide_Load()` to `Hide_load` -- remove the parentheses when using it as a callback.

Comment: Pick a question, not two

Comment: one question i can not get variable getid . load no complete

Comment: Suggest using the complete callback in `.load()`, see: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish the way you have posed the question.

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
function updatenewrow(getid) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test1.php',
    data: { id: getid },
    success: function (response) {
      if (response > getid) {
        $("#tr1").load("include/test.php?page=1");
      }
    }
  });
}
$("#tr1").load("include/test.php?page=1", function(response, status, xhr){
  if(xhr.status == 200){
    var getid = $("td:first", this).text();
    updatenewrow(getid);
  }
});
```

Hope that helps.